# Unity3D : Performance with multi-camera rendering with a lot of spheric meshes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rendering

I have an Unity 3D scene with several cameras looking at the same object (a huge brain mesh ~100k tri) but not necessary with the same point of view.

In the same 3D scene there is a huge number of spheric plots meshes (from 100 to 30000).

[image]

[image]

[image]

In all the cameras i have to display the brain mesh with a part of the plots meshes.

Depending on the camera view, each plot can have a different size (mesh filter and spheric collider), a different material (opaque or transparent) and can be visible or not.
The spheric collider must have the same size than the mesh.

I set up a shared mesh in common for each spheric mesh.
Their material can be one of the several shared materials i have defined.

Before rendering the scene, for each camera view in the OnPreCull function i have to define which plots are visibles and how they look.

This part can be very costly, i tried several things :

- setting gameobject inactive : too costly
- setting local scale to vector3(0,0,0) : better but i can see that the rendering is still done in the profiler
- setting a total transparent material : same result, but the in the profiler the rendering is now transparent instead of opaque
- setting a layer not in the cameras layers masks : huge script cost

I don't kwnow if i can make an efficient culling system with all theses cameras looking at the same point...

I welcome any new ideas.

Comment: hi, can you please explain what a "spheric mesh" is?  please include a 2nd and/or 3rd image showing what these are in detail.  please show one in the game view in close up and also in close up in the editor view.

Comment: I am confused about why you are doing culling: Unity includes superb culling, and it is not possible in any way to write faster culling.  Of course in some situations you have to "break something up". the classic example is say you have a racetrack 2km long.  obviously you have to break it up in to say 20 section of 100m - or else it will all be drawn no matter what! But that goes without saying. Once you break it up, nothing can do a better job that Unity of culling.  The culling engine is fantastic.

Comment: Note that you mention "Colliders"  I cannot see any reason at all you would use colliders in this project, pls explain if I misunderstand. What purpose do they have?

Comment: A spheric mesh is just a gameobject with a generated sphere as meshFilter, and with a sphere collider with a radius of 1. I must be able to click on each sphere in order to display information and perform some ROI operation.

Comment: I spoke about culling, because i found suspicous that i could see a lot of rendering work in the profiler while there was no visible spheres in the scene. (images added)

Comment: Ah, I see what your problem is.  Regarding the small spheres, how many do you have in the scene?

Comment: By the way, it is quite confusing to a 3D engineer to refer to them as "spheric mesh".  Say I had a dog in the scene.  (Of course it is "made out of mesh" -- what else could it possibly be?)  If I described that as a "doggic mesh" it would be very confusing - heh!  It sounds like you are talking about some *quality* of the mesh (such as a smooth mesh, tight mesh, mipmap mesh, or whatever.

Comment: Ahah, sorry for my (bad) english level, I feel ashamed about that... The maximum number of spheres could be 30k, with 20 cameras (extreme cases). But i have a system of ROI for delimiting special areas where the spheres could be seen.

Comment: Maybe i can try to add a LOD system for the spheres whith some steps in the triangle density.

Comment: 30k !   **No, you must use billboarding**  Please see my answer!  Do not use LOD, it is absolutely irrelevant here.

Comment: Note - you mention `OnPreCull`  Essentially, **you must not use this**, as it were.  It is an indication something is drastically wrong!  Anyway as explained in the answer ***you need eight brains here***  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First issue:

Regarding your specific question with the four dots.

Simply set the `renderer.enabled = false`, that's all there is to it.

Note however that as I mention in a comment, you would never try to "cull yourself" in Unity (unless I have misunderstood your description).

---

Second issue:

Regarding the small spheres.  I suspect you have very many in the scene.  You simply can't do that. In video games (the most difficult of all 3D engineering), you just do this with **billboarding**. It's how say "grass" is done in a scene. You can achieve this nicely with the particle system in Unity, or other techniques. An implementation is beyond the scope of this answer, but you will have to fully investigate billboarding. Simply it's a small flat image which always faces the camera in the render pass.

---

Issue 2B:

Note however that sphere *colliders* are wonderful, and you can use as many as you want. I'm sure this is obvious from base mathematical reasons. Side tip: often folks try to "write their own" thinking it will be faster. It's impossible to outwrite the 100? person-years of spatial culling scientific research in PhysX, and moreover they use the metal, the gpu, so you can't beat it.

---

Issue three:

Is there a chance you're using a *mesh* collider somewhere in the project? Never use mesh colliders, at all.  (It's extremely confusing they are mentioned or used in Unity; they only have one or two very specific limited uses.)

---

Issue four:

I'm confused about why you are *turning things on and off*. I have a guess.

## I suspect you are not using more than one "stage"!

There's an amazing trick about video games when you have more than one camera. In fact you have "offscreen" scenes! So you may have players in a dungeon or the like.  Off "to the side" you may have an entirely duplicate or triplicate setup of the whole thing running (you could "see it if the camera turned the wrong way") for the other cameras. (In the example you would have different qualities on the dopplegangers, coloring, map-style or whatever the case is.) Sometimes you make a whole double just to run physics calculations or address other problems.

[Fascinating extreme example of that sort of thing](http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/299823/view.html).

In short in your situation,

## You likely need one whole 'stage' of a camera *and brain* for each of the camera views!

Again this can be http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/299823/view.html but it is indeed the everyday thing. In your overall scene you will see eight happy brains sitting in a row, each with their own camera.  In each one you would display whatever items/angle etc are relevant.  (Obviously, if certain items are "identical, other than the viewing angle" you could use the "same brain with more than one camera": but I would not do that, best to have one-brain-one-camera for each view.)

I believe that could be the fundamental issue you're having!

Comment: I already tried, but enabling and disabling renderer from 1 to 5 times (for each camera) for each frame take a very amount of time. But thanks for the advice about the culling.

Comment: I'm confused about why you are turning things on and off - I have a suspicion!  it's possible you're missing one of the main tricks in 3D engineering!   I am about to address that in the answer.

Comment: I thought because of the heavy mesh that it would be better to have only one "stage", but now thanks to you it seems irrelevant to me, but i don't think i will have the time to rethink this part. I'm also using a mesh collider for the brain (i need sometimes to click on some triangles), but i can easily replace this with a raycast only when i need it (basically i have already all the stuff for doing it, all the c# code is a wrapper of my C++ DLL geometry library).However i didn't think about using billboarding i will investigate on it. Thank you very much for your time !

Comment: (1) it's my pleasure  (2) honest, I can assure you that you must use one brain per camera. ***there is absolutely no rendering performance hit***.  Each camera ***draws anyway*** .. you see?   Your performance improvement by switching to multiple brains ***will be incredible***, like 100x faster.  (3) if you are using `OnPreCull`, something is wrong, you "can't" use that.  (Note - the thing that is wrong is you are trying to "change the scene - between cameras!!!" you simply can't do that.)  (4) Regarding billboarding: yes, you will in fact, simply, absolutely have to change to billboarding.

Comment: A minor note: you'll likely have to get with the "layers" system in Unity, to more easily separate out stuff.